# Yeoman Backbone scaffold is 120MB and 11K files?

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman

Using [this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) generator to scaffold a backbone app gives me insanely big project of 11000 files. Probably because some of the generators are included in the project itself.

Is there an option to keep them generators global? The way Yeoman v0.9.6 was built? Or is it a bad practice?

Enlighten me would ya?

*--using yeoman 1 beta 5*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the generators globally:

```
npm install -g generator-mocha generator-backbone
```

But your dev dependencies for bower and npm will be added to your projects local file structure.

- node: `<project_root>/node_modules`
- bower: `<project_root>/app/bower_components`

They do take up a bunch of space but at least the scaffolded .gitignore filters them out of your commits =)

Comment: Scott, are you ok with that? I mean, do you not mind those packages taking 10 000% of the actual project size? I'm OK adapting to such mindset only if you are. It's just that when I first saw it, I panicked.

Comment: I don't mind the bower components being local. It is nice having the full source right there in the project so I can see the tests and un-minified source.  The 50megs of grunt-contrib modules seems excessive to me but to be honest I never really noticed it until I saw your question.  Pushing and cloning the repo's is fast so it does not introduce friction into my dev process.

Comment: @Birowsky see https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/40 and https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/944